# @Mapping with custom source and target variable is not working as expected when target has variable with same name as source

Tags: java, lombok, mapstruct

I have below Source and Target classes, i am using lombok for generating getters and setters

```java
public class Target {
    private String name;
    private String newName;
}

public class Source {
    private String name;
}
```

and let say if I want to map Source.name to Target.newName
I am using below Mapper class with @Mapping to specify source and target variables.

but once i compile the code and check the generated ClassMapperImpl
it is maping Source.name to Target.name and not to Target.new Name

```java
@Mapper
public interface ClassMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "name", target = "newName")
    Target sourceToTarget(Source s);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are both mapped when I try:

```
public class ClassMapperImpl implements ClassMapper {

    @Override
    public Target sourceToTarget(Source s) {
        if ( s == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Target target = new Target();

        target.setNewName( s.getName() );
        target.setName( s.getName() );

        return target;
    }
}
```

Please use ignore on the `name` property.

```
@Mapper
public interface ClassMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "name", target = "newName")
    @Mapping(ignore = true, target = "name")
    Target sourceToTarget(Source s);
}
```

Comment: this is a bug, right? We should create an issue I think.

Comment: Not sure. We always said we would key on target (not source). It is (deliberately) possible to map the same source to multiple targets with defined mappings. One could argue this should not happen for name based mappings tough..

Comment: Nope you are right. I didn't read that well. Even for name baaed it should always try to do the property name mapping for all non mapped target properties